# Can't boot past "press any key to boot USB" from windows 10 installation USB

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, windows-installation, rufus

**The problem**: My supposedly bootable win10 is visible in the boot menu. When I select it, it says press any key to boot USB... and that's as far as it goes. I'm left with an underscore blinking on the screen.

I have **previously been able to boot multiple linux distributions** from the concerned USB without error, so I'm pretty sure that's not the issue. **Relevant information**:

- ISO version is Win10 21H2 (the most recent)
- PC is an old Dell XPS 8300 (does not have UEFI)
- I used Rufus to create the USB with the following options:

  - NTFS file system
  - MBR partition scheme
  - Cluster size 4kB
  - Added fixes for old BIOSes

Please tell me if there's any important information I've left out.

Comment: I know this is very dumb question to ask, But just to be sure — Have you checked that your USB drive works properly on that device?

Comment: No question is a stupid question. Yes, yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

**FIX:**
This had a *really, really stupid* fix. Turns out Windows is just super slow to boot. Tooke 10 whole minutes to get past the blinking cursor!

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing any of the keys as soon as you select the boot device, I have the same problem, and I can boot by doing that. Alternatively, I have researched, and found that disabling rufus mbr fixes this, I think it is on the advanced options on rufus.